# Pass HEX value in PHP use GET method

Tags: php

If i have some code in **index.php**

```
if ($_GET['x']==="\x01\x03\x03\x07")
{
    echo 'OK';
}
```

So, how i could pass value x in url index.php?x=**???** to get output 'OK'.
Thanks!

Comment: `index.php?x=url`, one would think.

Comment: @Fred you mean `index.php?url=x`

Comment: if you're using `$_GET['url']`, then `index.php?url=x`

Comment: Yup :). Are you have anyway?

Comment: @panda_dth I see you edited your question.

Comment: Sorry, it's a writing mistake. Exactly is $_GET['x'] :D

Comment: @kennypu You're right, my bad.

Comment: @Fred now i'm wrong after the edit :(

Comment: do you need to write it yourself or use a code ? but you can manualy ad it `?x=\x01\x03\x03\x07`

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you want exactly. What I think you want to do, is make a form where you would use `action="get"` with either a hidden value, or an input. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Or use an "href" such as `<a href="www.example.com/index.php?x=value" >Link</a>`

Comment: Another example that could be useful `header("Location: index.php?x=value");`

Comment: @panda_dth Using a form `<form name="form" action="handler.php" method="get">...</form>`. Then inside handler `$x = $_GET['hex_value'];` and the rest of your code. Any of my examples answer your question?

Comment: You can also use `<form method="get" action="index.php?x=hex_value">...</form>`

Comment: @Fred "\x01\x03\x03\x07" isn't a normal string. Are you try? I tried some way but not ok :(

Comment: @panda_dth Check out this link on SO, best I can do for you now http://stackoverflow.com/a/13774366/1415724

Comment: @panda_dth I think whoever gave you this exercise to do, threw you a "curve ball". `\x01\x03\x03\x07` outputs nothing. Check out this link: http://codepad.viper-7.com/AtGMfU

Answer (score 0):

so, url must be like this:

```
... index.php?x=\x01\x03\x03\x07
```

and your $_GET must be like this:

```
$_GET['x'] = "\\x01\\x03\\x03\\x07";
```

It will return "OK"

To compare '\x01\x03\x03\x07'(hex value) with variable x that you sent in the url, first you have to change `'\x01\x03\x03\x07'` to `'\\x01\\x03\\x03\\x07'`. Why ? because if you don't double the '\' you won't be able to compare these.

So, you have to place the hex in a variable like this:

```
$hex = "\x01\x03\x03\x07";
```

and you will compare 'x' with edited $hex (the value be "`\\x01\\x03\\x03\\x07`").
to make edited/fixed $hex  we have to use a function, str_ireplace().

here's the example:

```
$hex = "\x01\x03\x03\x07";
$hex_able_to_compare  = "\\x01\\x03\\x03\\x07";
$fixed = str_ireplace($hex,$hex_able_to_compare,$hex);
if ($_GET['x'] == $fixed){
echo "OK!";
}
else {
echo "Not OK!";
}
```

So you can still compare your hex with place your hex to `$hex` variable.
But  the problem is: what if the the hex value is dynamic? we should make the value of `$hex_able_to_compare` as dynamic too,. :D

Comment: Sorry about that :D, my aim is to compare with HEX value "\x01\x03\x03\x07" :)

Comment: I found it! :D here's the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, you tried compare with operation ===. It'll fail :D

Comment: why do you use triple "=" to compare?

Comment: Because i've an excercise, my mission to get string 'OK' with piece of code above, i'm searching for solution for a long time and i've been trying many way :D

Answer (score 0):

To passing the hex value in URL you need character "%" before hex code. For example, %20 stand for space character.
So URL you need is:

```
index.php/x=%01%03%03%07
```

You can references HTML URL Encode [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm)

P/s: I think you are playing ctf.wargamevn.vn ;))