# Replace utf8 literals in string

Tags: php, utf-8

I am receiving from an external service a string with some utf8 literal in it.

```
$a = $param1;
echo $a;

\xe7\xe3
```

How can I convert $a (an utf8 string with 8 characters) to 'çã'?

I know I can use strtr with a map of substitutions, but I think that maybe there is a better way.

Simplifying the example, I have a simple web page:

```
<?php
echo '<html><body>'.$_GET['aa'].'</body></html>';
```

And I call it with `?aa=\xe7\xe3` parameter

The browser shows `\xe7\xe3` but I want to show `çã` like if I had declared with double quotes `"\xe7\xe3"`.

Comment: what is 'çã'? cant you use str_replace(array1, array2, $a)?

Comment: @zairwolf: I can use str_replace but 'çã' is just an example. There are dozens of characters to be replaced.

Comment: @mins: utf8_decode (or encode) just return the same string. My entire application is using utf-8.

Comment: I missed your point, sorry, I hope this one will be ok: [Convert Hex Code into readable string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774215/convert-hex-code-into-readable-string-in-php)

Comment: FWIW, that is *not* UTF-8. That's just a string containing ASCII characters, which happen to be an escape sequence notation for bytes which when decoded would decode to certain letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the tip from the comments I got a slight different algorithm working for me:

```
function decode_code($code){
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "@\\\(x)?([0-9a-f]{2,3})@",
        function($m){
            return utf8_encode(chr($m[1]?hexdec($m[2]):octdec($m[2])));
        },
        $code
   );
}
```