# echo a unicode string with a variable

Tags: php, unicode

1)

```
$stringToDecode = "\x2e";
echo "X $stringToDecode X";
```

results in "X . X"

2)

```
$stringToDecode = "x2e";
echo "X \$stringToDecode X";
```

results in "X \x2e X"

How can I echo a unicode string or escape it with a variable as its content.

(I wish to loop through all Unicode strings capture the content to a variable and check from alternate Unicode encodings of characters that all works ;) but stuck on how to echo and escape a variable string :)

Any help would be awesome, I've tried output buffers, and {} encasing string variables without any luck

Answer (score 0):

`\$` is not a meaningful metacharacter, so it's passed through as a literal `\` and a variable $stringtodecode, so your var will contain `X \x2e X`, which IS a unicode escape.

Comment: Thanks :)  is there a way to set the var to the evaluated form of the unicode escape the "." not the \x2e?

Comment: not really, unless you somehow "execute" the string, e.g. eval() in some way. it was built wrong, and the only way to fix it is to rebuild it from scratch

Comment: Thanks I looked into an eval and still outputs the same content as best as I can code it, is only going to run as a script so no security issue.  Would it be  possible to share how you would code it to eval the combined variable and "\" to output "." or any other php method that might work, if no worries and thanks for the direction so far

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774215/convert-hex-code-into-readable-string-in-php