# How to decode this characters in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a string like this

> \x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A1,\x22name\x22\x3A\x225.\x20ker\x5Cu00fclet,\x20R\x5Cu00e9giposta\x20u.

I don't know what kind of code is but I can decode it though this website http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/, is there any function to decode it? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate [Convert Hex Code into readable string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774215/convert-hex-code-into-readable-string-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Hex Code into readable string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774215/convert-hex-code-into-readable-string-in-php)

Comment: using the functions they answere there it returns "\x5B\x7B"id"\x3A1,"name"\x3A%. ker\x5Cu00fclet, R\x5Cu00e9giposta u" so it ain't converting at all, only half