# How to encode a string into hexadecimal representation?

Tags: php, character-encoding, encode

what is type this encoding?
`"\x73\164\x6f\x72\141\147\145\x3a\154\x69\x6e\153"`

How to encode `"storage:link"` string as above encode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Hex Code into readable string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774215/convert-hex-code-into-readable-string-in-php)

Comment: @HafezDivandari no i've already read this  question

Comment: i want how to convert string to this encoding not decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is a mixture of hexadecimal and octal representation of "storage:link":

```
\x73\164\x6f\x72\141\147\145\x3a\154\x69\x6e\153
  ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
 hex oct hex hex oct oct oct hex oct hex hex oct
```

According to [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php#47663), you may convert your binary string into hex represented text like this:

```php
$hexStr = bin2hex("storage:link");       // 73746f726167653a6c696e6b
$hexStr = chunk_split($hexStr, 2, '\x'); // 73\x74\x6f\x72\x61\x67\x65\x3a\x6c\x69\x6e\x6b\x
$hexStr = '\x' . substr($hexStr, 0, -2); // \x73\x74\x6f\x72\x61\x67\x65\x3a\x6c\x69\x6e\x6b
```

The final output would be:

```
\x73\x74\x6f\x72\x61\x67\x65\x3a\x6c\x69\x6e\x6b
  ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
 hex hex hex hex hex hex hex hex hex hex hex hex
```